# Determine canonical fields of action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, action

I'm working on an exercise which asks me to determine the canonical fields, and their equations of motion, of this invariant action:

$$
S = \int d\tau \sqrt{g_{\tau\tau}}\left( \frac{\tilde m}{2} g^{\tau\tau} \frac{d}{d\tau} x^\mu \frac{d}{d\tau} x_\mu - V  \right),
$$

where $\tilde m=1/2$ and $V=m^2$.

I don't know what a canonical field is and I don't know how to determine them from the action. Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to derive the pair of coordinates and their corresponding momenta.

The coordinates are just the variables your action is formulated in so $x^{\mu}$ and $g_{\tau \tau}$.

The definition of canonical momenta is

$$ p_{\mu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}^{\mu}}, $$

where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lagrangian density (the integrand in the action), and the dot stands for derivative wrt $\tau$.

It is a simple calculus exercise to derive the explicit formula for $p_{\mu}$ in terms of $x$ and $\dot{x}$ which you of course should do yourself, because we don’t do your homework for you on here ;)

There is no canonical momentum corresponding to $g_{\tau \tau}$, because it doesn’t appear with derivative wrt $\tau$ in the action. We call such variables Lagrange multipliers. They generate constraints on other variables. Your values of $p$ are not all independent. They in fact obey a constraint, which for vanishing $V$ reads $p_{\mu} p^{\mu} = m^2$ which is the famous Einstein’s energy-momentum kinematic relation. It can be derived by requiring that the variation of the action wrt $g_{\tau \tau}$ vanishes:

$$ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial g_{\tau \tau}} = 0. $$

Let me know in the comments if you have further questions!

**Update:** sorry I didn’t realize $g$ was the internal 1-dimensional metric on the worldline, I thought it was the spacetime metric. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot. If I want the equation of motion of $g_{\tau\tau}$ should I simply take the drivative of it with respect to $\dot{x}$?

Comment: @Linus sorry I’ve made a mistake. I thought $g$ was the spacetime metric. I’ll try to edit my answer.

Comment: @Linus I edited my answer please take another look

Comment: Thanks your help has been great. But is the equation of motion for $g_\tau\tau$ the one written above? If I write it out and solve for $g_{\tau\tau}$ I get: $g_{\tau\tau}=\frac{1}{3\bar{m}}(\dot{x^\mu}\dot{x_\mu})^{-1}m^2$ which if I put it in the action equation gives me an intergrand which is proportional to $\sqrt{\dot{x^\mu}\dot{x_\mu}}^{-1}$ but I would like to have one which is proportional to $\sqrt{\dot{x^\mu}\dot{x_\mu}}$ such that I recover the action for a free relativistic particle.

Comment: $g_{\tau\tau}d\tau ^2=\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$

Comment: I found what I did wrong and I have solved the problem. I just didn't understand the argument as to why $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial g_{\tau\tau}}=0$?

Comment: @Linus I was actually wrong again. I thought about a different action, the particle analogy of the Polyakov action from string theory. That action has $g$ as a dynamical field which doesn’t enter the Lagrangian with derivatives, hence it generates the constraint as I described in the answer. I now realize that in your simplified action $g$ isn’t dynamical, but it is externally given. So it is let among the caninocal coordinates and doesn’t generate the constraint. I’m sorry to have made so many mistakes :(